# Question about meaning of " apiece" in this context

Tags: word-meaning

> "Tomorrow I expect a very tough match. Maria is a champion and she knows how to manage the finals."After just one break **apiece** it was Kvitova who edged a first set tie-break and the Czech looked on her way to her first final of the season when she led 3-1 early in the second.Halep responded by taking the next seven games to level at one set all and go an early break ahead in the decider.The fourth seed then broke the Kvitova serve once more to move ahead 5-2 and served the match out in the next game."I knew it was going to be a tough match," said Kvitova."She beat me in the New Haven final, so I was looking forward to revenge. It was a long match and was a good fight throughout. She was just better in the end, but it was still a good match for me."

- When saying "apiece" , does it mean " each person" ? One break each person?

Comment: Please ask one question per question.  Here, you are asking many questions.  (Unfortunately, it isn't clear what most of them are.)

Comment: You've asked several questions lately which contain many questions in one. I'm afraid that's not how we do things at ELL, so I'm going to have to close this as too broad. Please try to ask one clear question at a time in the future.

Comment: @wendikidd - Sorry, I edited my question.

Comment: I've voted to reopen following the edit, but there's not much to say except that [***apiece*** here means ***each***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apiece). It's just a slightly stylised/formal/dated usage.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct it means "one break for each (person/group/team)"

Wordnik is great: https://www.wordnik.com/words/apiece#discuss

So is Onelook: http://www.onelook.com/?w=apiece&ls=a. With Onelook, I would hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> while clicking on a couple of definitions so they come up in separate tabs.

Of course, in google all you have to type is [`define apiece`](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+apiece) or any other word you want defined.